# Regex pattern matches exactly n times

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a pattern *123*234*567 that repeats exactly three times (like a combination of * and (.*?).

How do I write regex that the pattern can match only 3 times and not more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a non-capturing group and look for `3` consecutive matches of it. Not sure what you want to match between asteriscs, I've assumed digits and alphanumeric characters:

```
s = '*42*998 *123*234*567 *123*123'

re.findall(r'(?:\*(?:\d+|\w+)+){3}', s)
# '*123*234*567']
```